# Need faster CPU compared to NUC8i5 - what newer models are faster for C++ OpenCV processing?

Tags: intel, nuc

I currently am using Intel NUC 8i5 BEK with Ubuntu and C++ with 4K IP camera connected via RTSP.  It is working, and I am using OpenCV with Gstreamer VAAPI, but I need more CPU processing speed, as my frames-per-second rate is not fast enough when running all my frame processing to detect motion and bounding-boxes etc.

I want to make sure that my program is using the Intel NUC built-in hardware h.264 decoder and encoder (using OpenVINO), and have enough CPU speed to do lots of OpenCV frame processing and do it fast enough before the next video frame arrives.

**Since my 8i5 is several years old, which newer model would provide like 2x or 3x performance CPU speed increase for typical OpenCV C++ programs?**

Answer (score 0):

That does not exist... Yet. Since this uses an 8th gen Intel CPU, that is not very slow, even to today's standards like Intel Alder Lake or AMD Zen 3. (those are about +50% speed though, but not 2x or 3x). If your program is very multithreaded, you can get an ITX build with a Ryzen 9 5900X, and that would be faster (probably close to 2.5x) but if your program is not using a lot of threads, you may need to wait for Zen 5 for a 2x performance boost...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Hmmm, I guess I need to wait.   The program really doesn't lend itself to multi-threading... pretty much do this to the frame, then do that, then do this... building on the previous calculations... very straightforward but can't really do things in parallel.  Then before you know it,the next frame has arrived. So the processing speed limits the number of frames-per-second I can handle in the video stream.   Thanks again.